# I don't understand the error traceback gives me

Tags: string, pyth-lang

I'm currently trying to understand Pyth. I know Python quite well, but I don't get Pyth sometimes.

My code:

```
DhNKlNFzrKZaY@Nz;Y;hQ
```

It's just a basic script for reversing string, and traceback gives me ValueError,

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7ff2fde45c18>
```

Despite my Python knowledge I have no idea what does this error mean. Can you show me where is this error coming from?

Comment: You';ve supplied no code and used wrong tags. How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: tag created. not sure many people will see it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for creating tag. In that case where can I ask about Pyth?

Comment: here is okay. it's difficult to ask for something without tag. You did okay. but there's no a lot of people looking at _all_ the tags right now and this language is rather confidential. So maybe you'll get an answer, but not today.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you very much. I'll try to understand it myself 'til then. How can I close this question if I solve it? Is it okay if I post my own answer under it or it's unnecessary? (I don't use StackOverflow too often)

Comment: yes, you can answer your question if you manage to solve it. Be careful how you're answering: it has to help future readers.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are getting an error like [this one here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DhNKlNFzrKZaY%40Nz%3BY%3BhQ&input=abcd&debug=0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyth.py", line 771, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/app/macros.py", line 691, in eval_input
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fac26eb2b70>
```

First off, you use `z` and `Q` inconsistently. With your current code, input should have been taken like [this](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DhNKlNFzrKZaY%40Nz%3BY%3BhQ&input=%22abcd%22%0Aabcd&debug=0) instead:

```
"abcd"
abcd
```

When `Q` is used in a Pyth program, `z` implicitly jumps to the next line of input, it just skips whatever has been inputted before using `Q`. Instead, just use:

```
DhNKlNFzrKZaY@Nz;Y;hz
```

And the errors [should go away](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DhNKlNFzrKZaY%40Nz%3BY%3Bhz&input=abcd&debug=0).

I am not sure why you would want to perform string reversal that way, though. I use [`_z`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_z&input=abcd&debug=0) if the input is not quoted and [`_`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_&input=%22abcd%22&debug=0) alone otherwise, since `Q` is implicit at the end of any Pyth program.